# composer - vendor folder empty

Tags: php, composer-php, vendor

I got a website which I need to maintain and after looking at the files and code, I thought there are some missing files in `project/vendor` folder.

After talking to the current maintainer, he told me I need to use `composer` in order to see those files. I have installed `composer` but I don't know how to "fill" the folder with the files.

From reading online I understood I need to extract and install dependencies using the `composer.json` file but even after searching the web for more then an hour I didn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the root of you project and run

```
composer install
```

after that composer will download all package that are in the `composer.json` file in the `require` and `require-dev` section

Comment: are there any list of packages in the `composer.json` under the `require` or `require-dev` section

Comment: did you get any errors when running `composer install`

Comment: OK, I got it, I had to install `php7.0-curl`.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First, install the composer, take a look here [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), after this try to run `composer install`, in some cases I do update with `composer update` too.

Remember to run the command `composer install` on the same path where composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had to install `php7.0-curl` using the `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`.

After that I just used `composer install` again and it's good now